# fmincon throwing error on input arguments

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am working on an optimization problem where I want to maximize utility while searching over variables lx_init and kx_init. Each time I solve an issue with fmincon another one pops up. The error right now is..

"Not enough input arguments."
"Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue."

I have tried to trace back the error in debug mode but tracing back my error is proving difficult. The function is able to be evaluated on its own and spit back a value so I know the error is in the fmincon function. My Matlab experience is very minimal. I am sure there are other syntax errors I am guilty of and too naive to see. I will provide all variables so the code can be replicated.

A second question: I want to maximize my utility value here but also find the values of x and y given once the utility is maximized. However, we are also maximizing over lx_init and kx_init. How do I get the function to return x and y? Right now it is just returning the utility value.

Here is my function I am optimizing

```
function [utility, x, y] = utility_with_prod(gamma_X, gamma_Y, alpha_LX, alpha_KX, alpha_LY, alpha_KY, alpha_uX, sigma_U, sigma_X, sigma_Y, L_bar, K_bar, lx_init, kx_init)
   % X's production function
   x = gamma_X*((alpha_LX*lx_init^((sigma_X-1)/sigma_X)) + ((alpha_KX)*kx_init^((sigma_X-1)/sigma_X)))^(sigma_X/(sigma_X-1));

   % Y's production function
   y = gamma_Y*((alpha_LY*(L_bar-lx_init)^((sigma_Y-1)/sigma_Y)) + ((alpha_KY)*(K_bar-kx_init)^((sigma_Y-1)/sigma_Y)))^(sigma_Y/(sigma_Y-1));

   % utility function with nested production function
   utility = -(((alpha_uX*x^((sigma_U-1)/sigma_U)) + ((1-alpha_uX)*y^((sigma_U-1)/sigma_U)))^(sigma_U/(sigma_U-1)));
end
```

Here are my initial values

```
sigma_U= 0.5038;
sigma_X= 0.5029;
sigma_Y= 0.5029;

alpha_uX= 0.000236017865342454;

alpha_LX= 0.180813595922536;
alpha_KX= 0.819186404077464;
gamma_X= 1.768587207836113;

alpha_LY= 0.505368332690592;
alpha_KY= 0.494631667309408;
gamma_Y= 1.999942066647923;

lx_init = 1;
kx_init = 2;
L_bar = 3;
K_bar = 3;
x0 = [lx_init, kx_init];
```

and the optimization

```
utility = @(lx_init, kx_init)utility_with_prod(gamma_X, gamma_Y, alpha_LX, alpha_KX, alpha_LY, alpha_KY, alpha_uX, sigma_U, sigma_X, sigma_Y, L_bar, K_bar, lx_init, kx_init)

[optimal_lx_kx, utility_max, exitflag] = fmincon(utility, x0, [],[])
```

Comment: Your optimization problem does not involve any constraints, please consider using [fminunc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html) instead of `fmincon` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

- `x0` in `fmincon` is a vector, that's an n by 1 matrix or 1 by n,
  here 1 by 2 ---> `x0 = [lx_init, kx_init];`
- Function handle `@(lx_init, kx_init)` is different from `@([lx_init, kx_init])`.

  `@([lx_init, kx_init])`accepts only one input.

  `@(lx_init, kx_init)` accepts only two inputs, no more, no less
- Also input variable should not be predefined value
- Change `@(lx_init, kx_init)` to `@(x)` where `x(1) = lx_init` and `x(2) = kx_init`

To sum up

```
utility = @(lx_init, kx_init)utility_with_prod(gamma_X, gamma_Y, alpha_LX,alpha_KX, alpha_LY, alpha_KY, alpha_uX, sigma_U, sigma_X, sigma_Y, L_bar, K_bar, lx_init, kx_init)
```

is replaced by

```
utility = @(x)utility_with_prod(gamma_X, gamma_Y, alpha_LX, alpha_KX, alpha_LY, alpha_KY, alpha_uX, sigma_U, sigma_X, sigma_Y, L_bar, K_bar, x(1), x(2))
```

Comment: Ok so I changed my code to... `lx_init = .9;
kx_init = .4;
L_bar = 3;
K_bar = 3;
x0 = [1, 2];
x = [lx_init, kx_init];
%%

utility = @(x)utility_with_prod(gamma_X, gamma_Y, alpha_LX, alpha_KX, alpha_LY, alpha_KY, alpha_uX, sigma_U, sigma_X, sigma_Y, L_bar, K_bar, lx_init, kx_init);
` How do I add an input variable without pre-defining it? I am assuming you're talking about my x vector?

Comment: Additionally, for my lx_init and kx_init, the values being returned are just the initial values I used. Is there any reason why that is happening? They are just arbitrary values and I'm sure not the true utility maximizing ones.

Comment: utility = @(x)utility_with_prod(gamma_X, gamma_Y, alpha_LX, alpha_KX, alpha_LY, alpha_KY, alpha_uX, sigma_U, sigma_X, sigma_Y, L_bar, K_bar, x(1), x(2)); Don't reuse variable lx_init and kx_init into the utility function. Also x0 is not a random vector, according to your problem formulation x0 = [lx_init, kx_init]

Comment: By definition initialized variables never change their content, lx_init = .9; kx_init = .4 remains the same during the optimization process, x is the variable to be optimized. At t0, x = [lx_init, kx_init], at t1, x is no longer [lx_init, kx_init], x = [x(1), x(2)] . Optimization process keeps tracking the optimum value of x(1) and x(2). Note that  x(1) and x(2) start by x_init and kx_init change during the time while  x_init and kx_init are fixed values.